# Android Things project status: where to get information?

Tags: android, android-things

I am designing a product around a NXP Pico i.MX7D SOM, which is officially supported by Android Things. I need to be able to use Google services and would like to use a pre-certified solution to cut on certification/validation costs.

The latest Android developers post about Android Things (https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/02/an-update-on-android-things.html) makes me wonder whether Android Things is a viable solution for production.

The FAQ at https://developer.android.com/things/faq suggests that Android Things is either a commercial solution for OEM or a toy platform to play with as a developer.

- Where can I find more information about the Android Things platform?
- Is there an official place to ask for such information about Android Things?

Comment: I'm wondering the same....